# Shuffle a DataFrame while keeping internal order

Tags: python, pandas, shuffle

I have a dataframe that contains a pre-processed data, such that every 4 rows is a sequence (later to be reshaped and used for lstm training).

I want to shuffle the dataframe, but I want to keep every sequence of rows untouched . For example:
`a = [1,2,3,4,10,11,12,13,20,21,22,23]` will turn into something like: `a = [20,21,22,23,1,2,3,4,10,11,12,13]`.

`df.sample(frac=1)` is not enough since it will break the sequences.

Solution , thanks to @Wen-Ben:

```
seq_length = 4 
length_array = np.arange((df.shape[0]//seq_length)*seq_length)
trunc_data = df.head((df.shape[0]//seq_length)*seq_length)
d = {x : y for x, y in trunc_data.groupby(length_array//seq_length)}
yourdf = pd.concat([d.get(x) for x in np.random.choice(len(d),len(d.keys()),replace=False)])
```

Comment: Is there any other column in the frame which has one unique value per row sequence? For example, the column can have value 1 for sequence 1,2,3,4 and 2 for 10,11,12,13. If not, is it ok to add such a column?

Comment: @suicidalteddy 1,2,3,4 represent 4 rows of a certain column, not a row. I can add another column - but how will it help ? keep in mind that many values will repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need , `np.random.choice`

```
d={x : y for x, y in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//4)}

yourdf=pd.concat([d.get(x) for x in np.random.choice(len(d),2,replace=False)])
yourdf
Out[986]: 
   col1 col2
4     5    e
5     6    f
6     7    g
7     8    h
0     1    a
1     2    b
2     3    c
3     4    d
```

Comment: This assumes the index is numeric and continuous. Check out my answer that makes no such assumptions. (Though this is an improvement on your original answer to use `np.roll`)

Comment: @PMaschhoff your answer is ok , but only work for the when the len of df is n*4 , assuming the df is length 6 ,` np.arange(len(df)-2).reshape(-1, 4)` , `reshape` will failed

Comment: @Wen-Ben this is it! I tweaked your code a little bit - added as and edit in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can reshuffle in groups of 4 by... grouping the index into groups of four and then shuffling them.

Example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(12, 2)))
```

```
    a  b
0   5  4
1   7  7
2   7  8
3   8  4
4   9  4
5   9  0
6   1  5
7   4  1
8   0  1
9   5  6
10  1  3
11  9  2
```

```py
new_index = np.array(df.index).reshape(-1, 4)
np.random.shuffle(new_index)  # shuffles array in-place
df = df.loc[new_index.reshape(-1)]
```

```
    a  b
8   0  1
9   5  6
10  1  3
11  9  2
4   9  4
5   9  0
6   1  5
7   4  1
0   5  4
1   7  7
2   7  8
3   8  4
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you have the data in sequences of 4, then the length of the data frame should be in multiples of 4. If your data is in sequences of 3, kindly, change 4 to 3 in the code.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
```

Creating the table:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],'col2':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']})
>>> df
   col1 col2
0     1    a
1     2    b
2     3    c
3     4    d
4     5    e
5     6    f
6     7    g
7     8    h
>>> df.shape[0]
8
```

Creating the list for shuffling:

```
>>> np_range = np.arange(0,df.shape[0])
>>> np_range
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Reshaping and shuffling:

```
>>> np_range1 = np.reshape(np_range,(df.shape[0]/4,4))
>>> np_range1
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])
>>> np.random.shuffle(np_range1)
>>> np_range1
array([[4, 5, 6, 7],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
>>> np_range2 = np.reshape(np_range1,(df.shape[0],))
>>> np_range2
array([4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Selecting the data:

```
>>> new_df = df.loc[np_range2]
>>> new_df
   col1 col2
4     5    e
5     6    f
6     7    g
7     8    h
0     1    a
1     2    b
2     3    c
3     4    d
```

I hope this helps! Thank you!

Comment: @Wen-Ben roll with rotate the array i.e., bring last n indexes to the begining. It is clearly not performing any shuffle. Thank you!

Comment: When the length of df is not `n*4`, for example , it is has 6 rows, reshape will fail any thought ?

Comment: @Wen-Ben Yeah it will fail, but this depends on his data, when he is trying to shuffle his data which is already in the sequence of 4. Then the whole data should be in multiples of 4 for sure. If his data sequence is in multiples of three then he has to replace 4 with 3. Is my reasoning correct or did i miss something?

Comment: I am not sure about that , that is why I am not using reshape.

Comment: @sambasivarao thanks, but it is better not to make assumptions about the data - in my case there will be time when the data is not completely dividable by 4. See Wen-Ben's solution and my edit. Thanks!